# Ruby on Rails - Adding attribute to a ActiveRecord::Base but do not want to persist in Database, but should be in object json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a ActiveRecord::Base model called "Entry". It has a file attached to it. I am uploading files using Paperclip. Now, everything is merry when I using Views and using serverside code in the views. But now, I want to use the JSON and AJAX, render the front end in pure HTML5. So, for that, I will need the URL of the file. But paperclip only stores the file name, file content type etc and I can retrieve the url of the file with,

```
url = @post.myFile.url
```

So, I dont want to store the URL seperately in the DB, but want it to be a attribute to the "Post" model, and should be able to set it and get it and also, be the part of my JSON that is sent to the Client side.

In my controller I have the 'index' method as,

```
def index
@posts = Post.order("created_at desc")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

How will I change my Model? How will I change my Controller? I tried using

```
attr_accessor :file_url
```

in my Model and added the lines to the index method in the controller

```
@posts.each do |myPost|
   myPost.file_url = myPost.myFile.url
end
```

But could not succeed. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What error did you get using `attr_accessor`?  That should work

Comment: I dont get any error. But at the same time I dont get file_url attribute on my client side as well

Comment: The Answer for my question is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435768/cannot-access-attr-accessor-defined-variables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your goal. Do you want the file_url to be available from each post *before* you render your JSON? If so, you could do add api_attributes to your model, i.e.:

```
def api_attributes
  {
    id: self.id.to_s,
    title: self.title.to_s,
    ...
    file_url: self.myFile.url,
    ...
  }
end
```

Then you can render your json with something like:

```
format.json { render json: @posts.collect{|post| post.api_attributes} }
```

That will give you all of your Posts with all of the api_attributes you specified. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:
On one hand you were on the right track declaring an attribute accessor. Instead of the loop in the controller define it in your model.

```
def file_url
  myFile.url
end
```

The second problem is that when you're serializing an array in a controller, it is calling the default serialization of each element, which does not include your virtual attribute file_url.

The solution I recommend for this is the [ActiveModelSerializers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), that allows you to easily customize the serialization used by the controller. It's extremely easy to add your virtual attribute. (Note that overriding the as_json method in your model won't work because the array serializer will not use it)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem to control the formatting of your Json output.

Effectively, it adds view files for Json format, and you can add the URL as a node to the data.